# How to post image along with data using multipart entity in Android

Tags: java, android-studio

I am using MultipartEntity upload image with data, but I am unable to post. I have to post some details along with image. I don't know where is the problem, and also debug my code when hitting the post it not working. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
    String urlString = "url";
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
        FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile", bin1);
        reqEntity.addPart("Firstname", new StringBody("Firstname"));
        reqEntity.addPart("Mobilenumber", new StringBody("Mobilenumber"));
        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        resEntity = response.getEntity();
        final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        res.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        res.setText("n Response from server : n " + response_str);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload Complete. Check the server uploads directory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time research, i was able to post image with data to the server.I am follow the below link and modify as my requirement.I think this is helpful to anyone.[It is very useful to capture a picture and also i am able to post image with data by using this link](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);


        try {
            CustomMultiPartEntity entity=new CustomMultiPartEntity(new CustomMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void transferred(long num) {
                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                }
            });

            entity.addPart("FirstName", new StringBody(Person.getFirstName()));
            entity.addPart("LastName", new StringBody(Person.getLastName()));
            entity.addPart("Email", new StringBody(Person.getEmail()));
            entity.addPart("Password", new StringBody(Person.getPassword()));
            entity.addPart("Mobilenumber", new StringBody(Person.getMobilenumber()));
            entity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
```